# Activate auto-complete for C# in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

I have the problem, that I get some suggestions for autocompletion
(for example, I type "Cons" and I get the suggestion for "Console"), but these can't be applied with the Return-key.

Normally, the suggestion is fully blue, and gets attached, when I press 'enter', but for some time now, the suggestion has a blue border and pressing 'enter' results in a new line.
Where can I change these settings, so IntelliSense completes the words again, while I write them?
I already tried the IntelliSense-Settings in the C#-options, but these settings didn't change anything

Comment: Doesn't the "TAB" button provide the functionality you need?

Comment: Sure, but before, I didn't need the Tab-Button. I'm used to the auto-autocomplete

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are 2 different autocomplete  modus in Visual Studio, suggestion mode has the behavior you describe. Suggestion and standard, [explained here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/01/22/intellisense-suggestion-mode/). Press CTRL-ATL-SPACE to toggle between these modes.

Answer (score 5):

You likely inadvertently used the keyboard shortcut to toggle completion mode. You can correct it with the same shortcut or in the menu it's *Edit -> InteliSense -> Toggle Completion Mode*

[To change InteliSense from Suggestion mode to Completion mode in VS 2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rT9mi.png)

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, "*Toggle Completion Mode*" name changed into

*Edit -> InteliSense -> "Switch between automatic and tab-only Intellisense completion"*

[image: Intellisense]